# TypeScript define getter without exposing field

Tags: json, properties, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a class with getter, which is set up to return a value supplied to the constructor

```
class Example {
  private _field;

  constructor(field) {
     this._field = field;
  }

  get field() {
     return this._field;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I do `JSON.stringify(new Example('whatever'))` the `_field` is also serialized. My current workaround is to define the property inside the constructor with a closure

```
class Example {

  constructor(field) {
     Object.defineProperty(this, 'field', {
        get: () => field;
     }
  }
}
```

This way I don't need the field but now TS compiler complains that there is no `field` property. Is there a better way?

Or maybe I should find a way to exclude `_field` from being serialized?

Comment: Can you use a function? "getField() { return this._field; }"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @SlavaShp wrote is (in my opinion) the way to go, but you can put that into a single class which you can then extend to get this behaviour for every new class you need.

Something like:

```
abstract class JsonEncoded {
    private exposedFields: string[];

    constructor(fields: string[]) {
        this.exposedFields = fields;
    }

    public toJSON(): string {
        let json = "";
        this.exposedFields.forEach(fieldName => json += fieldName + ":" + JSON.strinify(this[fieldName]));

        return "{" + json + "}";
    }
}
```

Then you simply extend and inform the ctor what fields it should include:

```
class Example extends JsonEncoded {
    private _field;

    constructor(field) {
        super(["field"]);
        this._field = field;
    }

    get field() {
        return this._field;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach to the problem from the serialization part:

```
    let result = JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => 
    {
        if(key.lastIndexOf("_", 0) === 0) 
        {
            //Skip private fields assuming they all start with _
            return undefined;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    });
```

This might not be such a bad idea taking into account that if you are going to serialize complex objects you most likely will have to implement some sort of custom serialization to (for example) skip some of the fields based on business logic criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `toJson` method on your object to supply the properties to serialize. Stringify will use it.
You can look here [stringify documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)